# FTP inside a shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, freebsd

My host upgraded my version of FreeBSD and now one of my scripts is broken.  The script simply uploads a data feed to google for their merchant service.

The script (that was working prior to the upgrade):

```
ftp ftp://myusername:mypassword@uploads.google.com/<<END_SCRIPT
ascii
put /usr/www/users/myname/feeds/mymerchantfile.txt mymerchantfile.txt
exit
END_SCRIPT
```

Now the script says "unknown host".  The same script works on OSX.

I've tried removing the "ftp://".  - No effect
I can log in from the command line if I enter the username and password manually.

I've search around for other solutions and have also tried the following:

```
HOST='uploads.google.com'
USER='myusername'
PASSWD='mypassword'
ftp -dni <<END_SCRIPT
open $HOST
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASS
ascii
put /usr/www/users/myname/feeds/mymerchantfile.txt mymerchantfile.txt
END_SCRIPT
```

And

```
HOST='uploads.google.com'
USER='myusername'
PASSWD='mypassword'
ftp -dni <<END_SCRIPT
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
ascii
put /usr/www/users/myname/feeds/mymerchantfile.txt mymerchantfile.txt
END_SCRIPT
```

Nothing I can find online seems to be doing the trick.  Does anyone have any other ideas?  I don't want to use a .netrc file since it is executed by cron under a different user.

Comment: Can your host resolve `uploads.google.com`? Try `ping uploads.google.com` and `host uploads.google.com` and `telnet uploads.google.com ftp` to try to connect to their server.

Comment: Yes, I can log into the server if I do it manually:  
ftp uploads.google.com
and enter the username and password at the command prompt.

Comment: Excellent post, thanks for the formatting. Very easy to understand your issues. That said, I don't have access to FreeBSD system. Check out my ftp reply here, you may find some ideas. Good Luck!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054642/check-ftp-success-failure-inside-korn-shell-script/6059327#6059327

Answer (score 1):

[`ftp(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ftp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html) shows that there is a simple `-u` command line switch to upload a file; and since `ascii` is the default (*shudder*), maybe you can replace your whole script with one command line:

```
ftp -u ftp://username:password@uploads.google.com/mymerchantfile.txt\
/usr/www/users/myname/feeds/mymerchantfile.txt
```

(Long line wrapped with `\\n`, feel free to remove the backslash and place it all on one line.)

Comment: The server fails on the very first line saying unknown host.  It does not like the syntax of the initial ftp command with the username and password included.

Comment: @user77413, hrm. What does `which ftp` report? Maybe the `ftp` executable that is first in your `PATH` doesn't match the FreeBSD-supplied `ftp(1)`?

Comment: Did you forget the -u in your example?

Comment: @Pianosaurus, yes, yes I did. Thanks. (Love the name. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp $HOSTNAME <<EOFEOF
$USER
$PASS
ascii
put $LOCALFILE $REMOTETEMPFILE
rename $REMOTETEMPFILE $REMOTEFINALFILE
EOFEOF
```

Please note that the above code can be easily broken by, for example, using spaces in the variables in question.  Also, this method gives you virtually no way to detect and handle failure reliably.

Look into the expect tool if you haven't already.  You may find that it solves problems you didn't know you had.

Comment: This does not work.  It is trying to log into the FTP server using the username on the local server.  It seems to be trying to do the login before it is passing the user and pass variables.

Comment: In that case change to $USERNAME.  (I'm assuming here that you will input these values or otherwise define them before the ftp command.)

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

just a thought since this is executed in a subshell which should inherit correctly from parent, does an `env` show any difference when executed from within the script than from the shell?

Do you use a correct "shebang"?

Any proxy that requires authentication?

Can you ping the host?

Comment: I can log into the site manually, so it shouldn't be a ping problem.  I'm executing the script as my own user while testing, so I don't think that is the issue, either.

Comment: @user77413 Nevertheless, try it from within the script! You might be surprised...

Answer (score 0):

In BSD, you can create a [NETRC](http://www.mavetju.org/unix/netrc.php) script that ftp can use for logging on. You can even specify the `NETRC` file in your `ftp` command too using the `-N` parameter. Otherwise, the default `NETRC` is used (which is `$HOME/.netrc`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there's a difference in the environment between your shell-login, and the cron-job? From your login, run `env`, and look out for `ftp_proxy` and `http_proxy`.

Next, include a line in the cron-job that will dump the environment, e.g. `env >/tmp/your.env`.

Maybe there's some difference...Also, did you double-check your correct usage of the `-n` switch?